# Can't access my array in my other view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray

I made an NSArray called "bulletedArray" in my CRHViewControllerScript class and I am trying to access the same array and write it out in an NSLog in my CRHCommentSection class.  But, it isn't writing the array.  I know the array works and can write it out in the first class.  I think my method of getting to the next class is bad but here is what my code looks like.

"CRHViewControllerScript.h"

```
@interface CRHViewControllerScript : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> {

__weak IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;

}

+ (NSArray*)theArray;
- (IBAction)chalkYes:(id)sender;
@end
```

"CRHViewControllerScript.m"

```
#import "CRHViewControllerScript.h"

static NSArray* bulletedArray = nil;

@interface CRHViewControllerScript ()

@end

@implementation CRHViewControllerScript

+ (NSArray*)theArray {
return bulletedArray;
}

- (IBAction)chalkYes:(id)sender {

//get the text inside the textView
NSString *textContents = myTextView.text;

textContents = [textContents stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

//make the array
NSArray *bulletedArray = [textContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\u2022"];

//eliminate blank component at top of the array ("")
NSUInteger len = bulletedArray.count;
if (bulletedArray.count) {

    bulletedArray = [bulletedArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, len-1)]; 
}

//print out array 
NSLog(@"%@",bulletedArray); 

}
```

CRHCommentSection.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CRHCommentSection : UIViewController




@end
```

CRHCommentSection.m

```
#import "CRHCommentSection.h"
#import "CRHViewControllerScript.h"

@interface CRHCommentSection ()

@end

@implementation CRHCommentSection

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSArray *myArray = [CRHViewControllerScript theArray]; // This is how to call a Class     Method in Objective C
    NSLog(@"%@", myArray); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//make the array
NSArray *bulletedArray = [textContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\u2022"];
```

This creates a new variable named `bulletedArray` that is in the scope of

```
-(IBAction)chalkYes:(id)sender {
```

And so it masks the global one you have declared outside.  Simply remove the `NSArray*` from the beginning of that to fix the problem:

```
bulletedArray = [textContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\u2022"];
```

EDIT:

The nomenclature of instance-level methods and class-level methods is the difference between a method that begins with `-` or `+` respectively.

In your code, `+(NSArray*)theArray;` is a class-level method and can be invoked as `[CRHViewControllerScript theArray];` using the class name as the receiver of the method.

Whereas `-(IBAction)chalkYes:(id)sender;` is an instance-level method and must be invoked on an actual instance of the class, such as `[myCRHViewScript chalkYes:nil];`

As @user490696 pointed out, ideally you should be storing the array in an instance-level property and returning it from a method rather than storing it on a global scope.  For example, your `myTextView` variable is an ivar, or instance-variable.  This is a variable that is stored **per instance** of the class.  You could create a method that returns this variable like so:

```
-(UITextView*) getTextView
{
    return myTextView;
}
```

Comment: Also, I wouldnt say passing around data in statics is ideal, it would be better to use instance methods or properties and get a reference to the actual instance of the view controller you need.

Comment: @user490696 Yes, as a rule one should avoid the use of static globals, but I'm just particularly addressing the root of the problem here which is the scoping issue

Comment: could you give me an example of an instance method? Im a rookie.

Comment: @craig I elaborated a bit on instance methods in my question, if you'd like to know more, I would recommend the book [Programming in Objective-C](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Objective-C-Edition-Developers-Library/dp/0321811909/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1344454727&sr=8-1&keywords=programming+in+objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *bulletedArray = [textContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\u2022"];

//eliminate blank component at top of the array ("")
NSUInteger len = bulletedArray.count;
if (bulletedArray.count) {

    bulletedArray = [bulletedArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, len-1)]; 
}
```

The above code has no effect on the static you declared.  The local declaration

```
NSArray *bulletedArray //hides the static variable
```

Change the name of the local variable and then assign back to the static if that was your intent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it from an instance not from the class.

Just add a property to `CRHCommentSection`:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) CRHViewControllerScript *theControllerScript
```

and set in your App Delegate the instance of the `CRHViewControllerScript` to the `CRHCommentSection` instance like this

```
theCRHCommentSection.theControllerScript = theViewCRHViewControllerScript; //replace those Values with the actual ones
```

You can acess it in `CRHCommentSection` like this:

```
[self.theControllerScript theArray];
```